# Typing freezes the system for a short time

Tags: keyboard

So... i'm new in ElementaryOS and and I'm having some problems with freezes

Basically when I write something on the keyboard after a short time without writing anything, the system freezes for 1 - 3 secs and then returns to normal, the same happens when I use the keyboard volume control key.

This happens when I use keyboard shortcuts too. When I use shortcuts or other keys in the terminal eg the up arrow, when the system asks me for passwords in graphical interface and I type the password, then the system freezes.

Well, I run Elementary OS Desktop 5.0 Juno version and here is a log from *dmesg*: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/eUNpYMiY), I hope it helps

So... I started monitoring for `htop` if when I pressed a key, something froze my system, and I discovered that when I reproduce the reported bug, a strange application appears consuming 90% of my CPU for a few seconds, I also discovered that when I pressed Prt Sc to take a print of the process while the system was frozen, my keyboard stopped working soon after the system thawed, I hope these keyboard anomalies stop occurring when this error is fixed, this is the application:[image: The application consuming 90% of my CPU]

Comment: Be specific. If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer. [How do I ask a good question?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - | - You need to provide more information, is a laptop? which version do you installed? do you know how to use the command line? can you provide a log?, etc

Comment: In the screenshot, the process is `Xorg`. In simple terms, without it you won't have a graphical environment.

Answer (score 1):

### About the QUESTION

Have you tried using another keyboard? And/Or another USB port? Linux is very reactive in terms of a faulty hardware, could be "working" but having [EMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference). This is just a theory, but easier to test another hardware first than to keep trying to find the needle on the haystack

*(Could be useful if you provide Xorg's log [`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`] and the syslog [`/var/log/syslog.log`]. Remember to replicate the problem just before that way the problem will get into the log)*

---

### ANNEX

*(This didn't work for [MrPiva](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/16713/mrpiva), but I'll leave it as future reference.)*

To fix/help with what's on `dmesg`

```
[   20.081766] random: crng init done
[   20.081776] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
```

---

It seems to be a bug fixed in `plymouth/0.9.3-3` but Ubuntu and we have `plymouth/0.9.3-1`

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=897572#82

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442744

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=plymouth

---

### 1. RNG-TOOLS

You could try installing `rng-tools` to help with the issue

> Rng-tools. The rng-tools is a set of utilities related to random number generation in kernel. The main program is rngd, a daemon developed to check and feed random data from hardware device to kernel entropy pool. This is mainly useful to increase the quantity of entropy in kernel to make /dev/random faster.

Install `rng-tools`

```
sudo apt install rng-tools
```

If you installed `haveged`, remove it

```
sudo apt purge haveged
```

---

### 2. HAVEGE

> Linux entropy source using the HAVEGE algorithm
>    haveged is a userspace entropy daemon which is not dependent upon the
>    standard mechanisms for harvesting randomness for the system entropy
>    pool. This is important in systems with high entropy needs or limited
>    user interaction (e.g. headless servers).
>
> haveged uses HAVEGE (HArdware Volatile Entropy Gathering and Expansion)
>    to maintain a 1M pool of random bytes used to fill /dev/random
>    whenever the supply of random bits in dev/random falls below the low
>    water mark of the device.
>
> More information about HAVEGE is available at
>    http://www.irisa.fr/caps/projects/hipsor/

Install:

```
sudo apt install haveged

sudo systemctl enable haveged

sudo systemctl start haveged
```

ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/461466

---

Comment: The two lines did not disappear from dmesg: 
[6.004320] random: crng init done
[6.004322] random: 7 urandom warning (s) missed due to ratelimiting

Comment: Try again, just updated it

Comment: I tried installing `rng-tools` and `rng-tools5`, but that line did not disappear, but I also don't bother with it, since my boot is not totally late because of it

Comment: then why put the `dmesg` log... maybe if you give us the `syslog` or a portion of it from the moment you have that freeze... | Anyway `rng-tools` can be useful for other things in your system until we get the upgraded version of `plymouth`.

Comment: I updated the ask

Comment: There's nothing on the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` when the system freezes, I'll leave it here if it's useful [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/N8VpgXPy)

Comment: Yep, saw that. How about the keyboard?

Comment: So... I tested with a PS/2 keyboard and the error did not repeat itself, unfortunately I don't have another USB keyboard to know if the problem is with the keyboard or USB

Answer (score 0):

How to solve the issue when your system freezes for few seconds from time to time or at all and you have similar information in /var/log/syslog after typing the command?

```
grep 'Resetting' /var/log/syslog

May 18 06:30:35 DELL kernel: [  499.929699] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0
May 18 06:34:48 DELL kernel: [  753.880818] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0
May 18 06:40:02 DELL kernel: [ 1067.896600] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0
May 18 06:42:10 DELL kernel: [ 1195.896294] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0
May 18 06:45:50 DELL kernel: [ 1415.895996] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0
May 18 06:47:45 DELL kernel: [ 1530.903906] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0
May 18 06:54:21 DELL kernel: [ 1926.903712] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0
May 18 06:57:51 DELL kernel: [ 2136.887378] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0
May 18 07:01:29 DELL kernel: [ 2354.870458] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0
```

[Explanation for i915 chipset](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224240/why-is-the-intel-hd-graphics-driver-called-i915)

If you randomly encounter total system freezes, or it freezes from time to time for few seconds and you have i915 Intel GPU (Intel HD Graphics), the following kernel option is a workaround:

```
intel_idle.max_cstate=1 i915.enable_dc=0 i915.enable_fbc=0 i915.enable_psr=0
```

On new Intel GPUs Elementary OS and also Ubuntu freezes sometimes for few seconds, like it was in my case. So the solution is to do this:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

press insert (ins) button

and add this line intel_idle.max_cstate=1 i915.enable_dc=0 i915.enable_fbc=0 i915.enable_psr=0 to the list of options inside

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" ".
```

Then save that file and execute sudo update-grub from terminal. Reboot and it should be fixed.
it should look like this after the change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1 i915.enable_dc=0 i915.enable_fbc=0 i915.enable_psr=0"
```

I additionally installed rng-tools and haveged as advised above:

```
sudo apt install rng-tools
sudo apt install haveged
sudo systemctl enable haveged
sudo systemctl start haveged
```

Seems this solved issue totally.
I am monitoring this with command:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep 'Resetting'
```

There were errors like mentioned above, that is why I decided to compile the newest kernel. Solution provided in new post below or above.

Answer (score 0):

[image: No more error: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0]How to upgrade Elementary OS to the newest kernel.

Only for braves. It may be unstable.

I installed it, because my i915 GPU Intel HD Graphics was freezing the way it drove me mad.

```
mkdir /home/username/Downloads/kernel
mkdir /home/username/Downloads/amdgpu
mkdir /home/username/Downloads/i915
mkdir /home/username/Downloads/rtl

#### to get rid of missing firmware errors for amdgpu ####
cd /home/username/Downloads/amdgpu
wget https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries/files/4124959/firmware-radeon-ucode-rock_2.110_all.deb.zip
unzip firmware-radeon-ucode-rock_2.110_all.deb.zip
sudo dpkg -i firmware-radeon-ucode-rock_2.110_all.deb
```

Or use eddy to install this deb

Source: https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries/issues/82

My comment: I was brave enough.

```
#### to get rid of missing firmware errors for i915 ####
cd /home/username/Downloads/i915
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp -R /linux-firmware/i915/* /lib/firmware/i915/

#### to get rid of missing firmware errors for rtl (Realtek LAN and Wi-Fi adapters in my DELL) ####
cd /home/username/Downloads/rtl
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw
sudo cp rtl8168fp-3.fw /lib/firmware/rtl_nic 
sudo cp rtl8125a-3.fw /lib/firmware/rtl_nic

#### Download kernel 5.6.13 ####
cd /home/username/Downloads/kernel
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.6.13.tar.xz
tar -xf linux-5.6.13.tar.xz
cd linux-5.6.13

#### use 4 core/thread - if your processor have 4 cores ####
make -j 4

#### use 8 core/thread - if your processor have 8 cores ####
make -j 8

sudo make modules_install 
sudo make install 
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.6.13

#### ignore these errors below, just because those two bin files are not made yet ####
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu

sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
uname -mrs
```

Answer (score 0):

Update May 19th 2020.
I did the sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.3.0-51-generic
However tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep 'Resetting' still shows errors.[image]

So the upgrade of the kernel is the only solution.